# QML ComboBox with QAbstractItemModel

Tags: qt, combobox, qml, qabstractitemmodel

I'm implementing a simple list model, based on QAbstractItemModel:

```
class BaseListModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(BaseListModel)

    Q_PROPERTY(int length READ getCount NOTIFY countChanged)

protected:
    enum Roles{
        ModelDataRole = Qt::UserRole+1
    };

public:
    explicit BaseListModel(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~BaseListModel();

    virtual int getCount() const { return _data.size(); }

    Q_INVOKABLE virtual QVariant at(int index) const;

    /* 
        functions: add(), remove(), ...  
    */

public: // QAbstractListModel
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override {
       QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
       roles[ModelDataRole] = "modelData";
       return roles;
    }

signals:
    void countChanged();  
};
```

On QML code I could use a simple list, calling count or length for the content size and at(index) for an entry.
I'm using a single Role "modelData" to be compliant with the documentation:

> Qt documentation on models:
>
> Models that do not have named roles (such as the ListModel shown
> below) will have the data provided via the modelData role. The
> modelData role is also provided for models that have only one role. In
> this case the modelData role contains the same data as the named role.
>
> Note: model, index, and modelData roles are not accessible if the
> delegate contains required properties, unless it has also required
> properties with matching names.

For repeater or another delegate member it's easy to use it:

```
AnyView {
...
   model: my_model

   delegate: Text {
       text: modelData.description
   }
..
}
```

Now for the ComboBox to make it showing to the description, I try to set the textRole:

```
ComboBox {
...
   model: my_model

   textRole: "description"
...
}
```

But nothing happens ... the combobox remains empty.

I implement a new delegate (not so correct as of the original) using the modelData.description to show text in the popup list, but when the popup closes (after I select an entry) the combobox remains empty.

Has somebody an idea about what I do wrongly?

Something important: here what I try to achieve is to share a generic list of data from c++ up to QML. The model contains the list in C++ no need to create another one and is usable in the model.

```
template <class T>
class SimpleListModel : public BaseListModel
{
public:
    explicit SimpleListModel(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    SimpleListModel(const QList<T>& initList, QObject* parent = nullptr);

    int getCount() const override;

    QVariant at(int index) const override;

public:
    void append(T item);
    void insert(int index, T item);
    bool remove(T item);
    void removeAt(int index);

    void swapAt(int first_index, int second_index);

    const QList<T>& getList() const;

public: // QAbstractItemModel interface
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;

private: // finally the list
    QList<T> m_data;
};
```

Comment: *"Models that do not have named roles"* -- Your model does have a named role. You just named it "modelData". But you could have named it anything. Maybe you just want to call it "description"?

Comment: modelData allows me to get the instance and create a generic model. The idea is to implement in C++ a generic list: